# Celery & SQS exponential retry policy

Tags: celery, amazon-sqs

I'm looking for a way implementing exponential backoff / retry policy with Celery and SQS.

I like to use the `visibility timeout` mechanism SQS is offering and not celery `countdown` feature, as it is based on worker being active / not replaced with a different one.

Is there any kind of implementation supporting this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Celery already offers this since the 4.0 release. More about it in the ["Automatic retry for exceptions"](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions) section of the Celery documentation. In the case you want more than that, then you are on your own I suppose...

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like retry mechanism will not work with AWS SQS broker, since its using celery feature for countdown / ETA, not SQS visibility timeout. This means that in case where ETA>visibility timeout, two tasks will be executed

Comment: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/6cf4f40fc58fe8585721f4df95a1c77d25106dbf/celery/app/autoretry.py#L42 
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/brokers/sqs.html#caveats

Comment: I created a new project with the purposed solution

It is based on SQS visibility timeout mechanism https://github.com/galCohen88/celery_sqs_retry_policy

Comment: You should instead (IMHO) rather make a pull-request in Kombu and/or Celery to add this functionality.